# Можно ли вставлять класс к body сразу же после его загрузки?

Tags: вёрстка

Вопрос такой нестандартный... По большой развернутой причине, я пришел к тому, что чтобы обозначать стили, мне нужно тугглить определенный класс к `body`. Для этого я сделал такую иерархию загрузки:

```
<body>
 <script src="/assets/js/logic.min.js"></script>
```

А сам `logic.min.js` начитается с таких строк:

```
if (window.location.pathname == '/')
    $('body').addClass('hellopage').css('visibility', 'visible');
else if (~window.location.pathname.indexOf('/gallery/'))
    $('body').addClass('gallerypage').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Собственно, вопрос в том, насколько такой подход корректен с точки зрения человека разумного? :D
Как загружается страница как документ? Загружается тег боди, затем скрипт и только после скрипта, всё остальное?
Или нужно искать другие решения проблемы?
Потому что вроде как всё приосходит как обычно, а моя проблема решается таким способом...

А сама проблема звучит так: у меня не работает AoS скрипт, который подключается к тегу body. Для этого я создал внутри боди контейнер, который выполняет функцию этого тега - просто wrapper на всю величину body по сути. Но когда я отключаю тегу body скролл по вертикали, но включаю его тегу wrapper, скрипт не анимирует при скролле. Вот проблема более чем полностью.

Comment: `Или нужно искать другие решения проблемы?` - собсн вы не написали в чем заключается сама проблема, которая привела вас к таким логическим умозаключениям для совершения подобных действий

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, у меня не работает AoS скрипт, который подключается к тегу body. Для этого я создать внутри боди контейнер, который выполняет функцию этого тега - просто wrapper по сути. Но когда я отключаю тегу body скролл по вертикали, но включаю его тегу wrapper, скрипт не анимирует при скролле. Вот проблема более чем полностью. Щас добавлю.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, но проблема-то в не том, что он не работает в таких случаях. Он выполняет свою функцию, подключаясь к тегу body, за что его винить? Вопрос в том, корректно ли так тугглить классы или нет?